# What are the fragments that result from taking the Mass Spectrum of o-fluronitrobenzene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, mass-spectrometry

I am doing my online lab, and we are on mass spec right now. I am having a very tough time figuring out the shape of the fragments of o-fluronitrobenzene, especially the large peaks. Especially the one at 75, 83, and 111. I have been drawing fragmentation diagrams for a while now, but have come no closer to understanding what those fragments actually look like. [image]

I am fairly confident that the peak at 95 is a phenyl ion after the loss of entire nitro group. Also, the small peak at 125 also suggests the fragmentation of simply the nitrogroup(after the loss of the oxygen radical), which results in the cation being squarely on the Nitrogen. Although I am confused why the peak is relatively small. I suspect it is to do with the unfavorable oxygen radical being produced. My understanding is that if a compound is nitrogen contaning, that it will give a odd mass on the spectrum.

However, I think that it would not apply in this case as the nitrogen is bonded to two oxygen(both even), and the benzene give us all even masses. The only other odd mass atom would be the 19 Fluorine. It is my suspicion that the 75, 83, 111 peaks all do contain fluorine to some extent. I am just confused on how the fragmentation would lead to the masses with the fluorine on it. I know it contains fluorine, and most likely not a lot of the nitro group.

[image]

Comment: Why not to write down all options for the given mass ? Community members like to see some particular OP effect before starting the effort on their own

Comment: Well, tell us what some fragments can be according to you, for example lighter ones ones if you have trouble with heavier.

Comment: H=1, C=12, N=14, O=16, F=19. Try some basic arithmetics with involved chemical knowledge. C6H4NO2F=141. 141-83=58, 141-75=66, 141-111=30.

Comment: Don't equate the chemistry from the bench 1:1 to the inside of a MS.  Low concentration of the molecules (vacuum) and high energy (if you opt for the 70 eV of electron ionization) and subsequent fragmentation may yield ions and molecules you can't store in a bottle.  Because the relative intensity of peaks in MS depends on the ionization parameters it often is acceptable to attribute only the the key and/or the most intense ones.  So play with a sketcher (to determine the masses) for a putative attribution of the signals and put them on the table for discussion.